A concept called "Homogenisation" in coordinate geometry.


x³+y³+3xy=1 represent one side and one vertex of a triangle. Find
locus of centroid of the triangle

***.
I was stuck on this problem given by my maths teacher. I can't get my head around like where to start what should be my approach first of all!
At first I thought of converting the given equation in a homogeneous form but I can't even get any relation on that.

Rewrite the given equation as $$(x)^3+(y)^3+(-1)^3-3(x)(y)(-1)=0$$
$$\implies (x+y-1)(x^2+y^2+1-xy+x+y)=0$$
The equation of the side of triangle is $$\boxed{x+y=1}$$
Consider $x^2+y^2+1-xy+x+y=0$
Treat it as a quadratic equation in $x$ and find its discriminant. It will come $-3(y+1)^2$
For $x$ to be real, we must have $-3(y+1)^2\ge 0$ $\implies y=-1\implies x=-1$
The vertex of the triangle is $$\boxed{(-1,-1)}$$

Thanks a lot. I solved it myself today with the same process. It helps that I follow the right process. Thnx:)
